# How can I easily get the mean, median ,quartiles, etc. given counts of each value in R?

Tags: r, statistics

Suppose I have a data frame with a column for values and another column for the number of times that value was observed:

```
x <- data.frame(value=c(1,2,3), count=c(4,2,1))
x
#   value count
# 1     1     4
# 2     2     2
# 3     3     1
```

I know that I can get the weighted mean of the data using `weighted.mean` and the weighted median using the `weighted.median` function provided by several packages (e.g. `limma`), but how can I get other weighted statistics on my data, such as 1st and 3rd quartiles, and maybe standard deviation? "Expanding" the data using `rep` is not an option because `sum(x$count)` is about 3 billion (the size of the human genome).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried these packages:

1. `Hmisc` -- it has several weighted statistics, including weighted quantiles
2. `laeken` -- it has weighted quantiles.

Comment: Hmisc seems to have all the functions that I need. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Or try to back-transform it, and run the analysis the usual way:

```
dtf <- data.frame(value = 1:3, count = c(4, 2, 1))
x <- with(dtf, rep(value, count))
summary(x)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  1.000   1.000   1.000   1.571   2.000   3.000 
fivenum(x)
[1] 1 1 1 2 3
```

Comment: I said in the question that the total count is over 3 billion, which is too big to do this.

Answer (score 1):

To complete the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5306777/856624)
by [Prasad Chalasani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/415690/prasad-chalasani),
here is the code to complete the weighted median given
a column for values
and another column for the number of times that value was observed.
Note that it uses the `wtd.quantile` function from the `Hmisc` package.

```
require(Hmisc)

x <- data.frame(value=c(1,2,3), count=c(4,2,1))
##   value count
## 1     1     4
## 2     2     2
## 3     3     1

wtd.quantile(x$value, x$count, probs = 0.5)
## 50% 
##   1
```

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, I'll note that the S4Vectors package in Bioconductor provides an answer in the form of the "Rle" class, which lets you construct a run-length encoded vector that supports all the usual operations:

```
library(S4Vectors)
x <- data.frame(value=c(1,2,3), count=c(4,2,1))
y <- Rle(x$value, x$count)
mean(y)
median(y)
quantile(y)
```